# How can i catch parameter on maproute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, routes, maproute

How can i retrieve certain a section on routemap pattern.For instance i have a routemap pattern on my config file as `routes.MapRoute("", "Post/{slug}", new { controller = "Post", action = "Index" })` and i want to catch slug parameter inside global.asax.I tried as followed but it returns null.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = base.Context;
    if (context != null)
    {
        Response.Write(context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["slug"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
     var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));

     if (currentRouteData.Values["slug"] != null)
     {
         Response.Write(currentRouteData.Values["slug"]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe RouteData is not yet resolved when BeginRequest event is fired. You can use EndRequest instead.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = base.Context;
    if (context != null)
    {
        Response.Write(context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["slug"]);
    }
}
```

To make sure correct route is being used and slug parameter is actually supplied I'd recommend [Route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/)